# Why do you close questions before I have had time to clarify them?

Tags: discussion

Why are you closing [my question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/17333/41) in less than 24 hours? Not everyone lives by the computer. Some people even goes to bed and have a job, believe it or not! This makes me really angry.

Comment: thanks for bringing this up on meta -- I wish more users would do that.

Answer (score 2):

An explanation of the reason is provided with every closure:

> [Not A Real Question]: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

In addition, I provided a more specific explanation in a comment:

> This question has been closed as "Not A Real Question" because it doesn't state a specific problem and solicits opinions and recipes rather than facts and culinary knowledge.

The problem statement of the question does not elaborate beyond "it wasn't very good". This is the culinary equivalent of telling tech support that "it doesn't work". We cannot help with this problem. Why wasn't it good? What didn't you like about it? What were you expecting and how did the result differ from that expectation?

It then goes on to ask, "any tip?" This, similarly, is not soliciting any specific answer. Combined with the lack of a specific problem statement as above, it invites others to respond with literally any recommendation they might be able to think of. It's all up to somebody's personal taste and interpretation of the question.

Please read our [FAQ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq) as well as the [How To Ask](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) page. Most of this is explained in there, and participants here on meta are expected to be familiar with at least the former, preferably both.

Please also read the following meta question: [My question was closed! What should I do?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/690/41) which explains specifically what a closure means and how you can go about getting a closed question reopened.

Finally, note that neither our community nor our moderators (including myself) have any obligation or mandate to wait any length of time before closing or voting to close a question. We may sometimes extend grace periods to new members who are cooperative but inexperienced.  We do this **as a courtesy only** when we believe that (a) the question may have significant value once improved and (b) it is not actively doing harm as-is.

Although the original comment thread has now been deleted because it had become untenable and was unconstructive to begin with, other moderators can still see the deleted comments and will no doubt agree that the aforementioned spirit of cooperation was not evident in this instance. As of today the question is 4 days old; you have the freedom to edit your own question whenever you want (including when it's closed) and so far no edit has been forthcoming, only several angry comments and now an angry meta thread. The question will not be reopened in its current state.

If you want your question reopened, please read the material linked above and find a way to improve it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification that I was looking for. I get your point and I'm sorry if I offended you but it made me really frustrated to see my question close so fast. I have completely rewritten the question now and hope that it would be reopened soon.

Comment: @Godisemo, what new users don't usually understand is that closing a question is by no means final! Questions are often closed early so that bad answers don't trickle in *because* they can be reopened later once they're fixed.

Comment: @aaronut, I think it would be good practice on our (the mods) part, to include a note about closed questions being up for reopening if they're fixed when closing questions for new users. I can't find the blog post, but I remember seeing one about how sticky the site is being highly correlated to response to first questions or answers (i.e. users who get upvotes on their first answers tend to stick around).

Comment: I think it's important that we be welcoming to new users. There are some aspects of our site that are different from the internet as a whole, and new users often run afoul of these community standards. While we should certainly close things that are off topic and get people to adhere to our community standards, I try to educate with a comment when a user is clearly new. It gets kinda frustrating saying the same thing over and over again, but I think it is helpful to new users.

Comment: BTW, I edited the question a bit further, added a companion question, and reopened.

Comment: @yossarian: Please read the deleted comments in that question as well as the meta FAQ I linked to here. I'm sure you know that I try to do the same thing; however, not everybody responds positively to our "help". To paraphrase one of the ancient proverbs: We can only show them the door, they must walk through it.

Comment: @aaronut, so you did. My apologies.