# Should we provide instructions in simple English?

Tags: discussion

Occasionally we get new users that apparently are struggling with the English language *and* the rules of the site. I have the feeling that simply pointing them to the Tour and Help Center is not really helpful, because they may be too complicated to understand.

Should we collect a set of instructions or comment templates in Simple English, which we can copy-paste or link to in these cases?

I am not talking about translating each and every help page, just providing some very basic “how to get started here”.

Comment: We do have comment templates in [this Q/A](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1209/what-are-some-good-pre-canned-close-comments-for-new-users), but some of them are good examples of what I consider “too difficult to understand”.

Comment: Stephanie: agreed.  Heck, I'm a native english speaker, and I had to read some of those twice.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I handle this by explaining the rule directly in a comment, in a way that relates to the question.  I'm not convinced that a simpler version of the rules, still referred by link, would help.

Comment: If your comments (or anyone's) are generally understandable through partial language barriers, it might still be helpful to collect them for copy-pasting/starting points, even if links are tough?

Comment: It's a problem of making something both generic and clear.  That's a very very hard thing to do, whereas it's easier to make something clear when we can address the asker's question directly.